# Correct convert/marshall C Function and DLL Structure type to C#

Tags: c, c#-4.0, interop, marshalling

Can someone please help me convert my C structure/function into C#?

I believe I can call the DLL properly if I have able to correctly convert the function and marshal properly my structure.

Here is my struct and the function that uses it:

```
typedef struct UIclient_info {
  char name[50];
  int age;
  SECONDUSER *stParent;
} FIRSTUSER;

typedef struct ui_product_form {    
  char m_sCoupon;
  double amountTotal;
  char m_sErrorCode[50];
  SUBPRODUCT *pstSubProduct;
} PRODUCT;

typedef struct tagReport
{
  REPORTSUMMARY *pstRepsum;
  char errorMsg[100];
} FINAL_REPORT;

int Save(FIRSTUSER *myUser, PRODUCT *uiStructure);
FINAL_REPORT GenerateReport(FIRSTUSER *myUser, PRODUCT *uiStructure);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not work.  You can try it, I don't know whether or I handled the pointers correctly.  I won't be able to offer any other support on this.  If it works, then it works.  If not then... oh well.

```
//typedef struct UIclient_info {
//  char name[50];
//  int age;
//  SECONDUSER *stParent;
//} FIRSTUSER;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct FirstUser
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=50)]
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public IntPtr Parent;
}

//typedef struct ui_product_form {    
//  char m_sCoupon;
//  double amountTotal;
//  char m_sErrorCode[50];
//  SUBPRODUCT *pstSubProduct;
//} PRODUCT;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Product
{
    public char Coupon;
    public double AmountTotal;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=50)]
    public string ErrorCode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public IntPtr SubProduct;
}

//typedef struct tagReport
//{
//  REPORTSUMMARY *pstRepsum;
//  char errorMsg[100];
//} FINAL_REPORT;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct FinalReport
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public IntPtr ReportSummary;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=100)]
    public string ErrorMsg;
}

static class MyLibraryHelper
{
    //int Save(FIRSTUSER *myUser, PRODUCT *uiStructure);

    [DllImport(@"MyLibrary.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal static extern int Save(IntPtr myUser, IntPtr uiStructure);

    //FINAL_REPORT GenerateReport(FIRSTUSER *myUser, PRODUCT *uiStructure);

    [DllImport(@"MyLibrary.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal static extern FinalReport GenerateReport(IntPtr myUser, IntPtr uiStructure);
}
```